# How to replace text in a sentence but avoid certain words/letters?

Tags: c#, regex, string, loops, replace

So I have the full name of a person:

```
string fullName = "Bill Richardson";
```

Suppose, I have this sentence:

```
string sentence = "Richardson had a bike and he loved it";
```

But the sentence contains only the surname of the person, therefore I'm replacing it like this:

```
string modifiedSentence = null;
string[] senSplit = sentence.Split(' ');

foreach(string word in senSplit)
{
   if(fullName.Contains(word))
   {
      modifiedSentence = sentence.Replace(word,fullName);
   }
}
```

Now I would expect the modifiedSentence to be:

> Bill Richardson had a bike and he loved it

But apparently (I found the problem), if fullName contains even the word 'a', it gets replaced by the full name thus ending up with something like this:

> Bill Richardson had Bill Richardson bike and he loved it

That is a disaster, isn't it? :) How do I do this in an alternate way if possible? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
modifiedSentence = new Regex(string.Join("|", fullName
    .Split(' '))).Replace(sentence, fullName, 1);
Console.WriteLine(modifiedSentence);
```

Comment: Okay I will try this, can you explain the difference between this and my code? I need to understand it as well :)

Comment: @ProgrammingFreak it creates a regex which is a lot like `or`. So, it will look for Bill or the other word and replace it with fullname

Comment: @ProgrammingFreak check out my new code... the old one had syntax errors

Comment: @ProgrammingFreak glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know if the surname is the first or second in the fullName, you have to iterate on both, and instead of checking if it contains the word, test for equivalence between the two words.
Be careful that this doesn't work if the fullName is already contained in the original sentence.

```
var nameParts=fullName.Split(' ');
string modifiedSentence = null;
string[] senSplit = sentence.Split(' ');
foreach(string part in nameParts)
{
   foreach(string word in senSplit)
   {
      if(nameParts.Equals(word))
      {
         modifiedSentence = sentence.Replace(word,fullName);
      }
   }
}
```

While this could be done in a more compact inline way, I thought this would be easier to understand and more similar to your original code.